# move objects on screen in javafx

Tags: javafx, motion

I'm new to Javafx and I'm trying to make a game with it.
For this I need a fluid motion  of some objects on the screen.
I'm not sure, which is the best way. 
I started a testfile with some rectangle. I wanted the rectangle to move along a path to the click position. I can make it appear there by just setting the position. So I thought I just could make smaller steps and then the motion would appear fluid. But it doesnt work this way. Either it is because the movement is to fast, so I would need to make the process wait (I wanted to use threads for that purpose) or it is because the java intepreter isn't sequentiell and therefore it just shows the final position. Maybe both or something I didn't come up with.
Now I would like to know weather my thoughts on this topic are right and if there is  a more elegant way to achieve my goal.
I hope you can give me some advise!
regards Felix

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, in that there really isn't enough information about what you're trying to do. If you are just moving a rectangle along a path, a [`PathTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PathTransition.html) will do that, and in general the [Animation API](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXTE149) might be enough. For more complex games and simulations, you might need an [`AnimationTimer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html)

Comment: Hey thanx for your answer. I'll try to be more precisely: My goal is to make a car race. By cklicking on the screne you give your car a direction and some acceleration which will not be applied immideately. the movement will be executed after pressing a button. I tried the PathTransition you sugested. I works fine on the screne, but if I try to get the Position of the rectangle it just shows 0,0. I need the Position for further calculation e.g. if the car is still on the track and of course for the next movement. I' ll check on the Animation API and AnimationTimer next. Thank you again!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need to do for your car game is to read Daniel Shiffman's [The Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com), especially [chapter 6.3 The Steering Force](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-6-autonomous-agents/).

The book is very easy to understand. You can apply the code to JavaFX. I'll not go into details, you have to learn JavaFX yourself. So here's just the code:

You need an AnimationTimer in which you apply forces, move your objects depending on the forces and show your JavaFX nodes in the UI depending on the location of your objects.

Main.java

```
package application;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    static Random random = new Random();

    Layer playfield;

    List<Attractor> allAttractors = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Vehicle> allVehicles = new ArrayList<>();

    AnimationTimer gameLoop;

    Vector2D mouseLocation = new Vector2D( 0, 0);

    Scene scene;

    MouseGestures mouseGestures = new MouseGestures();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // create containers
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        // playfield for our Sprites
        playfield = new Layer( Settings.SCENE_WIDTH, Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT);

        // entire game as layers
        Pane layerPane = new Pane();

        layerPane.getChildren().addAll(playfield);

        root.setCenter(layerPane);

        scene = new Scene(root, Settings.SCENE_WIDTH, Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // add content
        prepareGame();

        // add mouse location listener
        addListeners();

        // run animation loop
        startGame();


    }

    private void prepareGame() {

        // add vehicles
        for( int i = 0; i < Settings.VEHICLE_COUNT; i++) {
            addVehicles();
        }

        // add attractors
        for( int i = 0; i < Settings.ATTRACTOR_COUNT; i++) {
            addAttractors();
        }


    }

    private void startGame() {

        // start game
        gameLoop = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                // currently we have only 1 attractor
                Attractor attractor = allAttractors.get(0);

                // seek attractor location, apply force to get towards it
                allVehicles.forEach(vehicle -> {

                    vehicle.seek( attractor.getLocation());

                });

                // move sprite
                allVehicles.forEach(Sprite::move);

                // update in fx scene
                allVehicles.forEach(Sprite::display);
                allAttractors.forEach(Sprite::display);

            }
        };

        gameLoop.start();

    }

    /**
     * Add single vehicle to list of vehicles and to the playfield
     */
    private void addVehicles() {

        Layer layer = playfield;

        // random location
        double x = random.nextDouble() * layer.getWidth();
        double y = random.nextDouble() * layer.getHeight();

        // dimensions
        double width = 50;
        double height = width / 2.0;

        // create vehicle data
        Vector2D location = new Vector2D( x,y);
        Vector2D velocity = new Vector2D( 0,0);
        Vector2D acceleration = new Vector2D( 0,0);

        // create sprite and add to layer
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle( layer, location, velocity, acceleration, width, height);

        // register vehicle
        allVehicles.add(vehicle);

    }

    private void addAttractors() {

        Layer layer = playfield;

        // center attractor
        double x = layer.getWidth() / 2;
        double y = layer.getHeight() / 2;

        // dimensions
        double width = 100;
        double height = 100;

        // create attractor data
        Vector2D location = new Vector2D( x,y);
        Vector2D velocity = new Vector2D( 0,0);
        Vector2D acceleration = new Vector2D( 0,0);

        // create attractor and add to layer
        Attractor attractor = new Attractor( layer, location, velocity, acceleration, width, height);

        // register sprite
        allAttractors.add(attractor);

    }

    private void addListeners() {

        // capture mouse position
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, e -> {
            mouseLocation.set(e.getX(), e.getY());
        });

        // move attractors via mouse
        for( Attractor attractor: allAttractors) {
            mouseGestures.makeDraggable(attractor);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Then you need a general sprite class in which you accumulate the forces for acceleration, apply acceleration to velocity, velocity to location. Just read the book. It's pretty much straightforward.

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;

public abstract class Sprite extends Region {

    Vector2D location;
    Vector2D velocity;
    Vector2D acceleration;

    double maxForce = Settings.SPRITE_MAX_FORCE;
    double maxSpeed = Settings.SPRITE_MAX_SPEED;

    Node view;

    // view dimensions
    double width;
    double height;
    double centerX;
    double centerY;
    double radius;

    double angle;

    Layer layer = null;

    public Sprite( Layer layer, Vector2D location, Vector2D velocity, Vector2D acceleration, double width, double height) {

        this.layer = layer; 

        this.location = location;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.acceleration = acceleration;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.centerX = width / 2;
        this.centerY = height / 2;

        this.view = createView();

        setPrefSize(width, height);

        // add view to this node
        getChildren().add( view);

        // add this node to layer
        layer.getChildren().add( this);

    }

    public abstract Node createView();

    public void applyForce(Vector2D force) {
        acceleration.add(force);
    }

    public void move() {

        // set velocity depending on acceleration
        velocity.add(acceleration);

        // limit velocity to max speed
        velocity.limit(maxSpeed);

        // change location depending on velocity
        location.add(velocity);

        // angle: towards velocity (ie target)
        angle = velocity.heading2D();

        // clear acceleration
        acceleration.multiply(0);
    }

    /**
     * Move sprite towards target
     */
    public void seek(Vector2D target) {

        Vector2D desired = Vector2D.subtract(target, location);

        // The distance is the magnitude of the vector pointing from location to target.

        double d = desired.magnitude();
        desired.normalize();

        // If we are closer than 100 pixels...
        if (d < Settings.SPRITE_SLOW_DOWN_DISTANCE) {

            // ...set the magnitude according to how close we are.
            double m = Utils.map(d, 0, Settings.SPRITE_SLOW_DOWN_DISTANCE, 0, maxSpeed);
            desired.multiply(m);

        } 
        // Otherwise, proceed at maximum speed.
        else {
            desired.multiply(maxSpeed);
        }

        // The usual steering = desired - velocity
        Vector2D steer = Vector2D.subtract(desired, velocity);
        steer.limit(maxForce);

        applyForce(steer);

    }

    /**
     * Update node position
     */
    public void display() {

        relocate(location.x - centerX, location.y - centerY);

        setRotate(Math.toDegrees( angle));

    }

    public Vector2D getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }

    public Vector2D getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation( double x, double y) {
        location.x = x;
        location.y = y;
    }

    public void setLocationOffset( double x, double y) {
        location.x += x;
        location.y += y;
    }

}
```

In the demo my sprite is just a triangle, I implemented a utility method to create it.

Vehicle.java

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.Node;

public class Vehicle extends Sprite {

    public Vehicle(Layer layer, Vector2D location, Vector2D velocity, Vector2D acceleration, double width, double height) {
        super(layer, location, velocity, acceleration, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public Node createView() {
        return Utils.createArrowImageView( (int) width);
    }

}
```

The demo has an attractor, in your case it'll be just a mouse click. Just click on the circle and drag it. The vehicles will follow it.

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class Attractor extends Sprite {

    public Attractor(Layer layer, Vector2D location, Vector2D velocity, Vector2D acceleration, double width, double height) {
        super(layer, location, velocity, acceleration, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public Node createView() {

        double radius = width / 2;

        Circle circle = new Circle( radius);

        circle.setCenterX(radius);
        circle.setCenterY(radius);

        circle.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        circle.setFill(Color.GREEN.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.3));

        return circle;
    }

}
```

Here's the code for dragging:

MouseGestures.java

```
package application;

    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;


    public class MouseGestures {

        final DragContext dragContext = new DragContext();

        public void makeDraggable(final Sprite sprite) {

            sprite.setOnMousePressed(onMousePressedEventHandler);
            sprite.setOnMouseDragged(onMouseDraggedEventHandler);
            sprite.setOnMouseReleased(onMouseReleasedEventHandler);

        }

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                dragContext.x = event.getSceneX();
                dragContext.y = event.getSceneY();

            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                Sprite sprite = (Sprite) event.getSource();

                double offsetX = event.getSceneX() - dragContext.x;
                double offsetY = event.getSceneY() - dragContext.y;

                sprite.setLocationOffset(offsetX, offsetY);

                dragContext.x = event.getSceneX();
                dragContext.y = event.getSceneY();

            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            }
        };

        class DragContext {

            double x;
            double y;

        }

    }
```

The playfield layer would be just some race track:

Layer.java

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class Layer extends Pane {

    public Layer(double width, double height) {

        setPrefSize(width, height);

    }

}
```

Then you need some settings class

Settings.java

```
package application;


public class Settings {

    public static double SCENE_WIDTH = 1280;
    public static double SCENE_HEIGHT = 720;

    public static int ATTRACTOR_COUNT = 1;
    public static int VEHICLE_COUNT = 10;

    public static double SPRITE_MAX_SPEED = 2;
    public static double SPRITE_MAX_FORCE = 0.1;

    // distance at which the sprite moves slower towards the target 
    public static double SPRITE_SLOW_DOWN_DISTANCE = 100; 

}
```

The utility class is for creating the arrow image and for mapping values:

Utils.java

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineCap;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineJoin;


public class Utils {

    public static double map(double value, double currentRangeStart, double currentRangeStop, double targetRangeStart, double targetRangeStop) {
        return targetRangeStart + (targetRangeStop - targetRangeStart) * ((value - currentRangeStart) / (currentRangeStop - currentRangeStart));
    }

    /**
     * Create an imageview of a right facing arrow.
     * @param size The width. The height is calculated as width / 2.0.
     * @param height
     * @return
     */
    public static ImageView createArrowImageView( double size) {

        return createArrowImageView(size, size / 2.0, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.3), 1);

    }

    /**
     * Create an imageview of a right facing arrow.
     * @param width
     * @param height
     * @return
     */
    public static ImageView createArrowImageView( double width, double height, Paint stroke, Paint fill, double strokeWidth) {

        return new ImageView( createArrowImage(width, height, stroke, fill, strokeWidth));

    }   

    /**
     * Create an image of a right facing arrow.
     * @param width
     * @param height
     * @return
     */
    public static Image createArrowImage( double width, double height, Paint stroke, Paint fill, double strokeWidth) {

        WritableImage wi;

        double arrowWidth = width - strokeWidth * 2;
        double arrowHeight = height - strokeWidth * 2;

        Polygon arrow = new Polygon( 0, 0, arrowWidth, arrowHeight / 2, 0, arrowHeight); // left/right lines of the arrow
        arrow.setStrokeLineJoin(StrokeLineJoin.MITER);
        arrow.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.SQUARE);
        arrow.setStroke(stroke);
        arrow.setFill(fill);
        arrow.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

        SnapshotParameters parameters = new SnapshotParameters();
        parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT); 

        int imageWidth = (int) width;
        int imageHeight = (int) height;

        wi = new WritableImage( imageWidth, imageHeight);
        arrow.snapshot(parameters, wi);

        return wi;

    }

}
```

And of course the class for the vector calculations

Vector2D.java

```
package application;



public class Vector2D { 

    public double x;
    public double y;


    public Vector2D(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void set(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double magnitude() {
        return (double) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    public void add(Vector2D v) {
        x += v.x;
        y += v.y;
    }

    public void add(double x, double y) {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
    }

    public void multiply(double n) {
        x *= n;
        y *= n;
    }

    public void div(double n) {
        x /= n;
        y /= n;
    }

    public void normalize() {
        double m = magnitude();
        if (m != 0 && m != 1) {
            div(m);
        }
    }

    public void limit(double max) {
        if (magnitude() > max) {
            normalize();
            multiply(max);
        }
    }

    static public Vector2D subtract(Vector2D v1, Vector2D v2) {
        return new Vector2D(v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y);
    }

    public double heading2D() {
        return Math.atan2(y, x);
    }

}
```

Here's how it looks like.

[image]

The triangles (vehicles) will follow the circles (attractor) and slow down when they get close to it and stop then.

Comment: Wow, Roland, the Nature of Code link is one of the best resources I have ever seen.  Thanks a lot for that...

Comment: @jewelsea: Yeah, he explains it very good. I bought it instantly. And the code can be easily mapped to JavaFX. He also explains each chapter on Vimeo in his channel, e. g. the [6.3 The Steering Force](https://vimeo.com/63089179) which I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Hi Roland, that was an amazing answer and will definitely come in handy:) I'll stick to the book. I'm working with the MVC-pattern so I will put the movement with the steering force inside a modell package. I wanted to use bindings to connect the model car with its corresponding view object and adjusted the vector class for that purpose. Unfortunately I have to bind everytime the move is executed. I would rather make the binding global but that doesn't work so far, since my initialize  method and the move method are seperate operations. Do you have any idea with that?

Comment: I'll make a new question with the binding. There is more that doesn't work. But thank you for your help! That was great!

Comment: Don't adjust the vector class to support binding. You need to perform all vector operations and after that's done you move the car. What you can do if you really want to use binding is to create x and y double properties and set the values in the display method, i. e. where I invoke the relocate method. The reason is that you want to apply force, then move and then you want to e. g. check if the destination would be outside the screen. But that must all happen before the car is moved on the screen.

Comment: Thank you again, it now works just fine with binding and the applied forces. I have extra x and y properties as you suggested. The movement is now smoth and easy adjustable. My object has an own acceleration, which I added to the other forces. I think I've done something wrong with the steering force but I'll figure it out since it is only an error in calculation. I make my calculation before my move starts and I use a timeline for this. I will post my code when the movement works the way it should:)